# IntelliJ can't see Desktop class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, path, classpath

So the problem is that IntelliJ just can not locate Desktop class. In fact it can not locate the whole java.awt package as far as I can see. I tried adding directory with those classes to CLASSPATH, but it didn't work. Neither did updating the SDK.

Has anyone ever had similar problem and could give me a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have managed to find solution to this question.

```
requires java.desktop;
```

This line has to be in module-info.java and everything will work fine.